# Dishonored only displays a black screen

Tags: wine, games, steam

I've recently bought and downloaded Dishonored. Sadly, however, when I try to run it, all I get is a black screen. No video, no audio, nothing.

I'm running it from Steam in Wine 1.14 on Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit). I know other people have it working perfectly with practically the same configuration. I'm guessing there's something simple I can do to get it working, and I've tried some things, but I don't really know what to do to make it work. I'd really appreciate any tips to get this game running.

Answer (score 1):

According [to this entry on WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26804&iTestingId=74337), the game works great running on Wine 1.5.14, but you need to install 'vcrun2008' from [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks).

Comment: vcrun2008 is already installed. [:-/

Comment: Still not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: when you try to run via Terminal, what's the output?